# In Azure ML Notebook (using serverless compute), how to read Specific Azure Key Vault values?

Tags: azure-keyvault, azuremlsdk

Using Azure ML SDK, I am able to Interactively Login,

```
ws = Workspace(subscription_id="my-subscription-id",
               resource_group="my-ml-rg",
               workspace_name="my-ml-workspace",
               auth=forced_interactive_auth)
```

and then I am trying to connect to the keyvault, and fetch secret values by connecting as below.

```
keyvault = ws.get_default_keyvault()
```

this connects to the default AzureML Keyvault instance and able to fetch secret values.
I need to connect to a specific key vault instance in another RG to fetch the secrets. Is there any way I can pass the instance name in ws object or is it not allowed?

I am using all default Azure RBAC access, and not Vault access policy.